# Converting indices to expression and back

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, rule

lets say I want to convert this

```
Subscript[PSternMat, 2, 13]
```

into this

```
PSternMat$2$13
```

I have written this rule

```
Subscript[PSternMat, 2, 13] /. {Subscript[n_, a_, b_] :> 
ToExpression[ToString[n] <> "$" <> ToString[a] <> "$" <> ToString[b]]}
```

which works fine.

But now I want to convert it back into it's original form. How can I do that

Thanks!

Comment: a quick solution might be something like `Apply[Subscript, 
 Through[{First, Sequence @@ Rest[#] &}[
   Map[ToExpression, 
    StringSplit[ToString[HoldForm[yourvar$123$12]], "$"]]]]]` but I don't know how robust it might be generally speaking

Comment: This seems like more trouble than it's worth, just because you want to use subscripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = PSternMat$2$13
Subscript@@ToExpression@StringSplit[ToString@c, "$"]
```

Comment: I don't think your answer does what the OP asks.. The 1st argument to the `Subscript` form should be a symbol, and the remaining two should be integers.

Comment: i didn't think about it, i checked the result and the structure    with TreeForm and they were equal, i didn't use SameQ, but now i think i fixed the error

Comment: This does work, but only in this specific case. If for instance the variable is squared and I want to convert it gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Can pattern matching be used for the task?

Comment: Maybe something using this:   `StringCases[ToString[PSternMat$2$13], n__ ~~ "$" ~~ a__ ~~ "$" ~~ b__]`